# Can we find a line L and a closed convex set S such that $L \cap S = \varnothing$, but each plane containing L intersects S

Tags: convex-geometry

> **Question**: In $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, Can we find a line L and a closed convex set S with $S \cap L = \varnothing$ such that for each plane $\Pi$, $L \subseteq \Pi$ we have $\Pi \cap S \neq \emptyset$?

How can we find these line $L$ and the closed convex set $S$?

Comment: Where does this question come from, please?

Comment: (And how does this look, one dimension down? In the plane, can we find a point $P$ and a closed convex set $S$ with $P$ not in $S$ but with every line containing $P$ meeting $S$?)

Comment: @GerryMyerson: This Question is coming from the textbook "Steven R. Lay - Convex Sets and Their Applications" Exercise 4.11

Comment: @GerryMyerson: One dimension down it is not true! Because there is a line containing P but not intersects S

Comment: OK, so what happens if you project the line down to a point, so each plane containing the line projects to a line containing the point. Do closed convex sets in 3 dimensions project to closed convex sets in 2 dimensions? Could you then apply the one-dimension-down result?

Comment: Your question asks, "Can we find a line ....?" but what I can see of Lay's book on google says "Find a line ...."

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Okay "Find a line L and a closed convex set S..." Can you help me with the solution?